# $H\cap K$ is normal maximal subgroup of $H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

if $G$ is a group and $H$ and $K$ are different normal maximal subgroup of $G$ .Prove that:

> $H\cap K$ is normal maximal subgroup of $H$.

If we suppose that $L$ is subgroup of $G$ which $H\cap K \le L \le H$ now how can I prove that $L = H\cap K$ or $L =H$?

Comment: What's "$H!$" ?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli - THe woes of math, having to worry about how you punctuate! :D

Comment: @Alec: I don't think the exclamation sign can be sentence punctuation -- the "if" that follows right after it is not capitalized.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well he did write `H!` rather than `$H!$`, so we await clarification. And the first "if" is not capitalised either.

Comment: Well, it was just that you typically do no see the exclamation mark at the end of an assignment (or of a sentence with an imperative verb), because it might sound unpolitely peremptory.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the isomorphism $HK/K \cong H/H\cap K$.

Comment: Can we say $G\cong HK$?

Comment: For every $x\in G$, $x(HK)=(xH)K=(Hx)K=H(xK)=(HK)x$, so $HK$ is normal and greater than $H$ or $K$. Then $G=HK$.

Comment: you mean,if I prove that $HK/ K $ is simple group then I can say that $H/ H\cap K$ is simple so $ H \cap K $ is normal maximal subgroup of $H$ .Am I right?

Comment: @ ajotatxe: Thanks for your help ! $G = HK$ so because K is normal maximal so $G/K$ is simple so $HK/K$ is simple and $H/H\cap K $ is simple so $H\cap K$ is normal maximal of $H$ .

Comment: I use this that G is a group and $H\unlhd G$ then $H$ is normal maximal subgroup of G if only and if $G/H$ is simple group !